# DocuSign API - How to share the envelope URL post calling the CreateEnvelope API?

Tags: docusignapi

For a use case we would like to share the document/envelope url to the user as part of the response to the API call that they make into our endpoint. Having explored the ESign API functionality, I did not find any way to extract the envelope url from the DocuSign ESign API that could be shared, hence explored the powerforms, but while doing that am am able to pass the text tab values to update the powerform as query string parameters, which is not secure enough. Any suggestions on which approach should I take to get the envelope url and be able to share it with the end user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to generate a long lived signing URL that can be shared over an email using the DocuSign API. To solve this problem, the solution needs to be broken down into two steps.

First, use the embedded signing ceremony with the clientUserID value set to a unique value, then get the envelope ID using the CreateEnvelope API. Map this envelope ID to a GUID and store this envelope ID in a database against that GUID and send the GUID appended to the web application URL like https://mywebapp.com?id=guide. The reason we want to share the GUID is to mitigate the risk of envelope ID being spoofed.
Now, this URL could be shared in the email.

If yours is a API based journey,just like it's in my case then you need to create a lean web app - mywebapp.com so that the URL can be created by appending the GUID to it, which enables the browser redirection in the second step as mentioned below.

Once the URL is clicked, that's where the second step of the solution comes into picture. In the second step, retrieve the envelope ID from the database using the GUID supplied in the URL and create a recipient view using the E-signature API. This will create a in-session view for the user to sign the document by redirecting it to DocuSign portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the envelope normally which will give you the option to supply the tab values, then after the envelope is created and obtaining the **envelopeId** you will be able to use the [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/) endpoint to create a URL that enables you to embed the recipient view of the DocuSign UI in your applications. If the recipient is a signer, then the view will provide the signing ceremony.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, we do not have any UI. It's totally API driven journey. We want to capture the URL of the envelope post creation, and share it as API response, so that the end customer can click on that URL/link and get to the envelope for signing. Please note - there is no web application involved, it's totally API driven journey

Comment: @AayushRastogi it is still the same URL, so rather than embedding it into an application you can send that link to trigger the signing process when its clicked

Comment: I want to grab the URL and send it to the user, perhaps in an email. But going through the documentation of [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/), it says that URL is time limited, so am afraid that by the time the user decides to sign the document, the URL would have expired.

Comment: In this case you should use the [remote signature request](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/) which will navigate the user to the DocuSign portal to sign the envelope you have sent to them